# Render scriban template from json data

Tags: c#, json, scriban

I would like to render a Scriban template with an `ExpandoObject` or any other data type that can be generated from a JSON string:

```
var json = "....";                
var dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);                    
var template = Scriban.Template.Parse("Hello {{ data.foo }}!");                    
var result = template.Render(dyn);
```

Scriban does not work with `ExpandoObject`s, as they are parsed as a list of `{ key = '', value = '' }` objects. Declaring a type for the data is not an option in my use case as the JSON schema is not known a priori.

- Casting ExpandoObject to dynamic shows the same behavior as using `ExpandoObject` directly.
- I've tried deserializing the JSON to `dynamic` which leads to an exception:

> System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: "Parameter count mismatch."

**Can I somehow convert the data or configure Scriban to render dynamic data?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the previous answer this is a solution for complex objects:

```
public static class ScribanRenderer
{
    public static string RenderJson(string json, string content)
    {

        var expando = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);
        var sObject = BuildScriptObject(expando);
        var templateCtx = new Scriban.TemplateContext();
        templateCtx.PushGlobal(sObject);
        var template = Scriban.Template.Parse(content);
        var result = template.Render(templateCtx);

        return result;
    }

    private static ScriptObject BuildScriptObject(ExpandoObject expando)
    {
        var dict = (IDictionary<string, object>) expando;
        var scriptObject = new ScriptObject();

        foreach (var kv in dict)
        {
            var renamedKey = StandardMemberRenamer.Rename(kv.Key);

            if (kv.Value is ExpandoObject expandoValue)
            {
                scriptObject.Add(renamedKey, BuildScriptObject(expandoValue));
            }
            else
            {
                scriptObject.Add(renamedKey, kv.Value);
            }
        }

        return scriptObject;
    }
}
```

It leverages the fact that complex properties of an `ExpandoObject` are always `ExpandoObjects` when it gets deserialized from JSON. It recursively adds `ScriptObjects` for complex member types and the object itself for all other properties to the ``ScriptObject`.

Please note that my solution uses Scriban's default member renaming, where `FirstName` becomes `first_name` and so on.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if the previous versions supported doing it, but it looks like this is more efficient, and the Scriban [example](https://scribanonline.azurewebsites.net/) ([github](https://github.com/nicholas-brooks/scribanonline/blob/master/Controllers/GenerateController.cs)) does this.

```
var json = "{\"name\":{\"first\":\"Maia\"}}";
var template = Template.Parse("Hello {{model.name.first}}");        
var result = template.Render(new { model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json) });

Console.WriteLine(result);

// Output: Hello Maia
```

Answer (score 2):

In cases when you have a simple object you can try something like this.

```
var json = "{\"Phone\":\"555000000\",\"Name\":\"Maia\"}";
var scriptObject = new Scriban.Runtime.ScriptObject();
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(json);
foreach (var prop in data)
{
   scriptObject.Add(prop.Key, prop.Value);
}
var templateCtx = new Scriban.TemplateContext();
templateCtx.PushGlobal(scriptObject);
var template = Scriban.Template.Parse("Hello {{Name}}");
var result = template.Render(templateCtx); // result will be "Hello Maia"
```